# Warning While Building Apk Warning: autovalue.shaded.com.google$.auto.common.$MoreElements$1

Tags: java, android, apk, building

When I build apk I get the warning, as shown in the image.Problem occurs when shrinking and minify option along with Proguard is enabled. Apk builds without problem when everything above is turned off. Can anyone help me to fix this error?. I tried adding autovalue dependency by searching on Stackoverflow. But still the problem persists.

Any Solution?
[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0Vxe.png]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38264829/9060113

Comment: well at least show us the error.  There's a red icon next to run tasks, but it collapsed.  You did show us the warnings, but normally warnings don't break the build.

Comment: @p.alexey I have tried that solution already and its not working.Hence asked.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx I have updated the thread.Yes i know warning doesn't break the build.But i couldn't find out whats causing it.It is a simple app with a fragments.And without proguard and shrinking option the apk build was around 25 - 50 Mb so applied abi filters for just 'armeabi-v7a' and brought app down to 10 Mb.I still like to reduce its size and hence applied proguard .But i am stuck with this error for days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution.

The Proguard file hasn't been linked properly.
For those who come across this problem.

In Android studio go to file - Project Structure .On left side Modules - app- and from tab select Build Types and under Proguard file Link it from your source.
Clean and Run.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these rules into your `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-dontwarn javax.lang.**
-dontwarn javax.tools.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn autovalue.shaded.com.**
-dontwarn com.google.auto.value.**
-dontwarn javax.servlet.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
-dontwarn autovalue.shaded.org.apache.commons.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log.**
-dontwarn org.apache.velocity.**
-dontwarn org.apache.tools.**
-dontwarn org.jdom.**
-dontwarn org.java.lang.**
```

And `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` into your  buildType with proguard in `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Can you add your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Added Kindly take a look :)

Comment: Have found a solution :)